# Georeferenced TIFFs that don't display in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

I have a few TIFF images that were georeferenced by a third-party using ArcGIS.
When I import them in QGIS, I have the following Layer Error:

```
IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0: libjpeg: JPEG datastream contains no image,IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0: libjpeg: JPEG datastream contains no image,IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0: libjpeg: JPEG datastream contains no image
IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0: libjpeg: JPEG datastream contains no image
```

Otherwise QGIS recognises them and puts them in the correct location (I can tell because it zooms properly when I select zoom to layer), but they are not displayed.
I tried to play around with symbology, but this does not seem to be the problem.
They work fine with ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: The "jpeg" references in the error messages are interesting. Can you get the Layer Properties/Information tab up for the layer and show us what it says? It seems jpeg files can be encoded into TIFF files but I see a few other Q's where people have had problems with the format. Letting us have a copy of one of the offending files would be really really useful if you can share it (or something similar with the same failure mode if you can't sure your actual files)

Comment: Image data in TIFF can be compressed with several different methods, including JPEG https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/compression.html. It seems that either the libtiff library, or the libjpeg library that handles the jpeg streams, consider that the image is invalid. Without a test image it is impossible to say anything more.

Comment: I found out that they are displayed if i super zoom on them. Here are the infos from the source tab as well as a copy of the georeferenced image: https://we.tl/t-NappGEKrGG